# Recording network streaming radios

Tags: linux, streaming, gstreamer, recording, internet-radio

I am writing a simple application for linux that will connect to a network radio and record the stream to a file. However as I record, I want on the fly to split the stream in smaller files (for example split the stream captured in files containing 3 minutes audio each). Moreover, my application must be able to handle various streaming systems (e.g shoutcast, icecast, mms etc).

So far I 've looked at various frameworks. At first Gstreamer seemed a good solution but I have not managed to create a working pipeline that will do the splitting without losing any data. I know that MPlayer and vlc can dump a stream to a file but splitting can not be done on the fly. Stremripper  does not work with mms streams. Can anyone point me to the right direction. I prefer to use a C or python framework but I am open to any suggestions:).

Comment: since you can read and play the radio stream, you also can record it from the master output

Answer (score 0):

gstreamer can be used for this scenario.

- for input you can use - souphttpsrc element, it supports (icecast, shoutcast)
- for mms - mmsrc source element can be used.
- to split the file into multiple small files use  "multifilesink" element.

gstreamer also has python bindings.